# SQL Server Always-on AG: database property TRUSTWORTHY on secondary replica different from primary replica

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In an environment with SQL Server 2014 (there are practically even this version still in use), I routinely checked for databases that had the TRUSTWORTHY property enabled.

I stumbled across a database that is included in an AlwaysOn availability group (readable secondary replica). For this database the `master.sys.databases` of the current primary shows a value of 0 for `is_trustworthy_on`, but on the secondary, `is_trustworthy_on` is 1.

How can this be? Is this a bug?

Comment: If you fail over, does the trustworthy property seem to stick with the role (i.e. "primary is always 0; secondary is always 1") or the server (i.e. "serverA is always 0; serverB is always 1"). If the latter, it seems that someone set that property while that server was in the primary role. The "fix" for this would be to fail over to that server and set trustworthy off.

Comment: Last failover was in March during a regular maintenance. At that time, nothing was changed related to database properties. Unfortunately, since this is a production critical system (24/7), the next failover will probably have to wait a bit. Will try exactly this way then. Thanks a lot!